# Magic method, decorator pattern, call_user_func_array is not working with reference

Tags: php, reference

I have this:

```
class A
{
    public function ok($a,$b)
    {
        echo __METHOD__.'<br>';
        var_dump($a,$b);
    }

    public function reference(&$a)
    {
        echo __METHOD__.'<br>';
        $a = 'cameFromReference';
    }
}

class B
{
    /**
     * @var A
     */
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(A $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array([$this->decorated, $name], $args);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
$b = new B(new A());
$b->ok('test', 'test2');
$a = -1;
$b->reference($a);
var_dump($a);
```

with `__call`, I want to transfer the method calls. Everything works fine, until I have to pass (and get back) a reference. Even if I change to:

```
return call_user_func_array([$this->decorated, $name], [&$args]);
```

then wrong number of parameters are passed.

Comment: Maybe [this note](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php#refsect1-function.call-user-func-array-notes) in php manual will be helpful for you. If I understand it properly - it may be not possible to implement in 5.4+

Comment: oh, I forget to mention, Im on 5.6 so it wont work anymore

Comment: You may try to play with reflection, since there is [ReflectionParameter::isPassedByReference](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.ispassedbyreference.php) that is available for both [ReflectionFunction](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) and [ReflectionMethod](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php), but it will take some time I think